# c# overload (extension)functions with default value arguments

Tags: c#, operator-overloading, overloading, optional-parameters

I don't understand why compiler doesn't see my first mult function

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

namespace Vector3ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensionsVector3
    {
        public static Vector3 mult(this Vector3 me, float x, float y=1.0f, float z = 1.0f)
        {
            return new Vector3(me.x * x, me.y * y, me.z * z);
        }

        public static Vector3 mult(this Vector3 me, Vector3 other)
        {
            return new Vector3(me.x * other.x, me.y * other.y, me.z * other.z);
        }
    }
}
```

And this doesn't work:

```
new Vector3(1,1,1).mult(1,1); //compiler says "no overload method 'mult' takes 3 arguments"
```

Why?

PS I would like to add that I am not getting any error while in VS editor, but this particular error pops up if I move to Unity(unity's console spits an error to me).

Comment: Is `mult()` in a public static class and is the namespace that class resides in accessible?

Comment: [here](http://pastebin.com/zMKJb3aK) paste bin. It's inside static class of namespace in which I can access from where I am trying to access the function. I can call the second method though. I can call the first function as well if I provide all three arguments.

Comment: @thumbmunkeys Just now. Still error.

Comment: Do add Vector3ExtensionMethods namespace in the clas where you use the method?

Comment: What this call would say: var vect = new Vector3(1,1,1); vect.mult(1,1); ?

Comment: @Random Negative, but vect.mult(1,1,1) works... and I am not happy with that. :( I want default value! grr c#!

Comment: @DmitriyFinozhenok I do have the namesapce. I can call the second method and first method as well(if I provide all the definitions rather than try to have default value)

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps (new Vector3(1,1,1)).mult(1,1)?